# concordance index in python lifelines

Tags: python, survival, lifelines

From this post ([Use median survival time to calculate CPH c-statistic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352183/use-median-survival-time-to-calculate-cph-c-statistic/352435#352435)), the author makes clear explanation that why we can use negative hazard scores to calculate c index.

In the lifelines document (https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#concordance-index), it mentioned that the syntax is concordance_index(df['time'], -cph.predict_partial_hazard(df), df['status']), which also make sence. I tested on the lung dataset thats in their packages, it works well.

But, when I created some random numbers, the c index is less than 0.5. Much appreciate if someone could simply explain this to me.

```
T = np.array([3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2])
X = np.array([6, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3])
E = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
concordance_index(T, -X, E)
```